# How to move Vector2 along angle?

Tags: libgdx, vector, angles

These are my Vector2's that I am using for this function.

```
public Vector2 position = new Vector2();
public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
public Vector2 movement = new Vector2();
public Vector2 direction = new Vector2();
```

Here is the function that I use to move the position vector along an angle. setLocation() just sets the new location of the image.

```
public void move(float delta, float degrees) {
    position.set(image.getX() + image.getWidth() / 2, image.getY() + image.getHeight() / 2);
    direction.set((float) Math.cos(degrees), (float) Math.sin(degrees)).nor();
    velocity.set(direction).scl(speed);
    movement.set(velocity).scl(delta);
    position.add(movement);
    setLocation(position.x, position.y); // Sets location of image
}
```

I get a lot of different angles with this, just not the correct angles. **How should I change this function to move a Vector2 along an angle using the Vector2** class from com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2 within the LibGDX library?

I found [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69497/how-to-move-an-object-along-a-vector), but not sure how to implement it.

---

**Update: I figured out part of the issue. Should convert degrees to radians. However, the angle of 0 degrees is towards the right. Is there any way to fix this? As I shouldn't have to add 90 to degrees in order to have correct heading. New code is below**

```
public void move(float delta, float degrees) {
    degrees += 90; // Set degrees to correct heading, shouldn't have to do this
    position.set(image.getX() + image.getWidth() / 2, image.getY() + image.getHeight() / 2);
    direction.set(MathUtils.cos(degrees * MathUtils.degreesToRadians), MathUtils.sin(degrees * MathUtils.degreesToRadians)).nor();
    velocity.set(direction).scl(speed);
    movement.set(velocity).scl(delta);
    position.add(movement);
    setLocation(position.x, position.y);
}
```

Comment: What is correct heading?

Comment: By convention, in mathematics an angle of 0 radians (or degrees) means pointing to the right. Angles move counterclockwise from there.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could switch your cos with sin and vise versa if you're really against adding 90 in your function, but I think adding 90 is a perfectly viable solution. Once a function works, you shouldn't have to care what's inside of it.